# UITableViewCell delete button gets covered up

Tags: uitableview, ios7, xcode5

UPDATE:

Thanks to information from "Evgeny S" I've been able to determine that what is covering up the delete button is the cell background. I had the following function called at the beginning of cell init:

```
- (void) setupGradientsWithHeight:(int) the_height
{
    CAGradientLayer* gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];

    gradient.frame  = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x,
                                 self.bounds.origin.y,
                                 self.bounds.size.width,
                                 the_height);

    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:218.0f/255.0f
                                           green:218.0f/255.0f
                                            blue:220.0f/255.0f
                                           alpha:1.0].CGColor,
                       (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:180.0f/255.0f
                                           green:180.0f/255.0f
                                            blue:184.0f/255.0f
                                           alpha:1.0].CGColor,nil];

    UIView* bgview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];

    [bgview.layer addSublayer:gradient];
    [self setBackgroundView:bgview];
}
```

The problem is solved by NOT adding the backgroundview. However, I'm wondering how it might be solved while preserving the gradient background for each cell?

One of two things could be happening. When the delete button appears the background view is either being shifted and then back - or its size is being decreased and then back.
I tried messing with the width component "self.bounds.size.width" for the gradient frame but I still don't see how that could be affecting things because this function is only called once at cell initialization.

ORIGINAL POST:

I had created an App in Xcode4 under iOS6 SDK - but after loading things up in the new environment (Xcode5 and iOS7 SDK) I ran into a problem. Note that I have resolved all build errors and warnings that came up when making the transition.

I have a tableview with some cells. After entering edit mode, if one clicks the red toggle button to initiate delete mode for a cell - the animation begins and the "Delete" button appears - but only briefly and is then suddenly re-hidden.

Another strange thing I should note is that even while the delete button is covered up - you can still click where it should be and delete the cell.

I've tried to take out as much of my "custom code" as possible, I've removed functions that I had overridden and tried to take things back to an original state as possible - but to no avail.

At one point I had seen a strange message in the output log:
"attempting to set a swipe to delete cell when we already have one....that doesn't seem good". For some reason the message is on longer appearing and I can't seem to remember what I was doing at the time.

Any thoughts or recommendations on what might be causing this?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vCAGzSaOwp4

Comment: Without implementation details of your custom cell, it's really hard to guess the problem...

Comment: This issue has been fixed by iOS 7.0.3.

Comment: I have continued to encounter this problem in iOS 7.0.4.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is one of countless bugs in iOS 7.

For some reason the backgroundView is moved by iOS over the delete button.
You can work-around this by subclassing your backgroundView and implementing the setFrame function of your derived view like this:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"7.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) {
        // background view covers delete button on iOS 7 !?!
        [super setFrame:CGRectMake(0, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
    } else {
        [super setFrame:frame];
    }
}
```

As a side note: you can avoid the need for a separate sublayer by subclassing and implementing layerClass in your derived view:

```
+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [CAGradientLayer class];
}
```

Comment: Great solution. This is the way to go to prevent re-covering the delete button. With iOS6 I used to have the deletion control on the left change from (-) to (I) but now the row slides. Is there a simple way to preserve the iO6 way in iOS7, or do I just have to accept that part of my row is going to get hidden when it slides.

Comment: Can u please explain it little briefly. How to subclass the background view in custom cell and default cell.

Answer (score 13):

I fixed this by finding the delete button view and bringing it to the front. I did this in layoutSubviews in a UITableViewCell subclass.

Here's a small bit of code that should give you an idea of how to do it:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {

        for (UIView *subview2 in subview.subviews) {

            if ([NSStringFromClass([subview2 class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView"]) { // move delete confirmation view

            [subview bringSubviewToFront:subview2];

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and I know the code is running, but my delete button is still disappearing.

Answer (score 5):

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self sendSubviewToBack:self.contentView];
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work for me, with custom formatted cells this made the text on my cells invisible. -rrh

Answer (score 2):

You can use the colorWithPatternImage but for me it was easier to use the self.layer.content.
for example :

```
cell.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"singleRow.png"].CGImage;
```

That way the image don't get stretched and it doesn't have to be in exact size.
That way the delete button doesn't get covered up by the cell background image.
By The Way: these custom gradient backgrounds don't seem to match up with the iOS 7 basic appearances, do you think that could be a grounds for not approving the app?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing an issue where my UITableView was in editing mode and after deleting 2-3 rows I get message "attempting to set a swipe to delete cell when we already have one....that doesn't seem good" logged and then user Interaction on all cells except one cell gets disabled.

I solved this issue by

```
[myTableView setEditing:NO animated:NO];
[myTableView setEditing:YES animated:NO];
```

after each deletion.

This workaround worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the problem by setting background you want for the uitableview and setting  `cell.backgroudColor = [UIColor clearColor];` and `cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

Comment: This has me going in the right direction, thank you. I've updated my answer to include suspect code. Any insight on the new details?

Comment: I replaced this code: 

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_background_normal.png"]];
        self.backgroundView = view;
with the following code:

[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_background_normal.png"]]];

in customization of my custom cell and that did the trick.

Comment: I'm still not sure how I can use that in my code since I have a CAGradientLayer that needs to be added. Either way, I've given up on the gradient since when I remove it the delete button is visible and the plain white look of the cells kind of match the design pattern of iOS7 anyways. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I've run into a similar problem and have a work around the that puts the Delete button on top of my cell content but the animation is a bit ugly. When done the button is visible and does the right thing.

Create a custom subclass of UITableViewCell and add the following code:

```
-(void)didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
{
    if (state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask ) {
        [self sendSubviewToBack:self.contentView];

    }

    [super didTransitionToState:state];
}
```

Improvements on this approach or other pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

### Cleaner, General Solution

Assuming an iOS7 only app, with a technique similar to that posted by chris above, I believe the approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19416870/535054 is going to be cleaner.

In this approach, you don't need to subclass your backgroundView, which could be different for different cells.

Place the code in the answer I've linked to above, in the root of your custom table cell hierarchy, and all of your table cells (that inherit from it), get the fix whenever they use the **backgroundView** or **selectedBackgroundView** properties.

Comment: A visual of what's going on is available in this article describing the fix: http://sohail.io/2013/10/21/ios7-uitableviewcell-and-covered-delete-button/

Answer (score 1):

I'm still seeing this problem after updating to XCode 5.0.1 but I've used a different workaround which is to use a boolean named `changeTitle` set to NO in `willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath` and set to YES in `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` if we're not in row deletion mode.

Then I use that variable to pad the button title with some extra spaces in `titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0 && changeTitle) {
        return @"        Delete";
    }
    return @"Delete";
}
```

It works for me but the main drawback is that the confirmation area is wider than you think it is so an unintentional delete is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have project started in iOS 6 SDK and use storyboards, this might be the issue with constraints. Try deleting all of cells constraints and fall back to suggested. This could resolve issues with delete button. I had such problems in two different projects and they were resolved described way.

Answer (score 0):

And one more workaround:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if ([ [ [UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare: @"7.0" options: NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) {
        if (iOS7 == YES) {
            self.backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.backgroundView.frame.origin.y,
                                                   self.backgroundView.frame.size.width, self.backgroundView.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a better way just make sure you subclass UITableviewController for better performance and add this code

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

[super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;

if(editing){
    [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
    //other codes to run if needed
}else{
    [self.tableView setFrame:frame];
    //other codes to run if needed
}
```

}