# UITableViewCell covering delete button on swipe left

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am posting this question, specifically related to iOS 7.

When I swipe cell to left, the delete button appear correctly, but the cell is not moving left enough, which results in the delete button being covered by the cell for nearly half of its width.

The cell is a class extending UITableViewCell, and in Storyboard there's a UIView with some child views in it, but for the rest it is just a plain cell.

The custom class is not implementing any drawing mechanism.

Comment: I just wonder why the question has been downvoted...a comment would help to improve the question.

Comment: Please post some code or a sample project to reproduce the problem.

Comment: This [Related Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938719/uitableviewcell-delete-button-gets-covered-up) has a more information in the answer but still hasn't solved my problem.

Comment: I've found a work around with this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19058749/690293).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some custom code configuring your cell, I would remove the code for this and add it back. There has to be something that you've written in your code to cause this to happen. Usually, this functionality works right out of the box. Post your code so that we can see what's causing the issue.