# UITableViewCell content overlaps delete button when in editing mode in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I am creating a `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCell`s. iOS 7's new delete button is causing some problems with the layout of my cell.

If I use the "Edit" button, which makes the red circles appear I get the problem, but if I swipe a single cell it looks perfect.

**This is when the Edit button is used:**

```
[self.tableView setEditing:!self.tableView.editing animated:YES];
```

[image: Content overlaps the delete button]

**This is when I swipe a single cell:**

[image: Content is placed right]

As you can se my labels overlaps the delete button in the first example. Why does it do this and how can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableViewCell delete button gets covered up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938719/uitableviewcell-delete-button-gets-covered-up)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try using the `accessoryView` and `editingAccessoryView` properties of your `UITableViewCell`, instead of adding the view yourself.

If you want the same indicator displayed in both editing and none-editing mode, try setting both view properties to point at the same view in your `uiTableViewCell` like:

```
self.accessoryView = self.imgPushEnabled;
self.editingAccessoryView = self.imgPushEnabled;
```

There seems to be a glitch in the table editing animation in IOS7, giving an overlap of the delete button and the `accessoryView` when switching back to non-editing state. This seems to happen when the `accesoryView` is specified and the `editingAccessoryView` is `nil`.

A workaround for this glitch, seems to be specifying an invisible editingAccessoryView like:

```
self.editingAccessoryView =[[UIView alloc] init];
self.editingAccessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: I don't get the "if you want the same indicator" and this does not seem to solve the problem for me.

Comment: But this is not about showing the same indicator. It's about the layout of the cell. Or the delete button being too big when there is a delete indicator.

Comment: indeed. This is a solution to overcome the problems associated with the way UITableViewCells are laid out in iOS7. The accesoryViews seems to be laid out correctly in all scenarios, so this answer suggest using them, instead of adding views to the cell yourself.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that in edit mode the cell's contentView changes in size. So either you have to override `layoutSubviews` in your cell and support the different frame sizes

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect contentFrame = self.contentView.frame;
    // adjust to the contentView frame
    ...
}
```

or you take the bait and switch to autolayout.

First I thought setting `contentView.clipsToBounds` to `YES` could be an ugly workaround but that does not seem to work.

Comment: I was using self.bounds (which does not change) instead of self.contentView.frame. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I've resolved this problem with set up constraints without width only leading and trailing

Comment: Can you be specific please, I have exactly the same issue in iOS7

Comment: I've got next views stack: cell - contentView - backgroundImageView;

Comment: I've got next views stack: cell - contentView - backgroundImageView;  when i set up constraints for backgroundImageView like: leading = 0; top = 0; height = someHeight; width = someWidth; then deleteButton was showing under backgroundImageView. I've changed constraint width onto trailing. BackgroundImageView started changing size and deleteButton  is showing fully

Comment: This solved my issue too. Adding the correct constraints allowed the cell's contenView to reposition it self correctly when in editing mode.

Comment: @MishaVyrko, Hi Misha, I am also struggling with the same issue. When compiling for iphone 5 delete button is invisible. For 6th iphone I can see it fine. I am total newbee about constrains and I cant find backgroundImageView property in constrains menu. I have latest xCode. Could you help please

Answer (score 2):

As tcurdt mentioned, you could switch to autolayout to solve this issue. But, if you (understandably) don't want to mess with autolayout just for this one instance, you can set the autoresizingMask and have that turned automatically into the appropriate autolayout constraints.

```
label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use this method in your custom TableViewCell class you can get the perfect answer,

Here `self` is `UITableviewCell`

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {

[super layoutSubviews];

    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {

    for (UIView *subview2 in subview.subviews) {

        if ([NSStringFromClass([subview2 class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView"]) { // move delete confirmation view

            [subview bringSubviewToFront:subview2];

        }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

And if any one want to adjust the Delete Button Size, Use the following Code

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];

    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {

        for (UIView *subview2 in subview.subviews) {

            if ([NSStringFromClass([subview2 class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView"]) { // move delete confirmation view

                CGRect rect = subview2.frame;
                rect.size.height = 47; //adjusting the view height
                subview2.frame = rect;

                for (UIButton *btn in [subview2 subviews]) {

                    if ([NSStringFromClass([btn class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationButton"]) { // adjusting the Button height
                        rect = btn.frame;
                        rect.size.height = CGRectGetHeight(subview2.frame);
                        btn.frame = rect;

                        break;
                    }
                }

                [subview bringSubviewToFront:subview2];

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to remove this problem is that add an image in cell and set it in Backside.

```
      UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgImg.png"]];
      imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, yourCustomCell.frame.size.height);
      [yourCustomCell addSubview:imageView];
      [yourCustomCell sendSubviewToBack:imageView];
```

If your text would overlap the delete button then implement Autolayout. It'll manage it in better way.

One more case can be generate that is cellSelectionStyle would highlight with default color. You can set highlight color as follows

```
      yourCustomCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Set your table cell's selection style to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone. This will remove the blue background highlighting or other. Then, to make the text label or contentview highlighting work the way you want, use this method in yourCustomCell.m class.

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (highlighted)
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
     else
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

I hope you understand it in a better way.

Comment: How is that supposed to help!?

Comment: Hi @tcurdt, if you add an image at the background of the cell and then set it via sendSubviewToBack method it will stop overlapping. And if you apply setHighlighted method in your customCell class then it will help you to set highlighted color of cell.

Comment: How is adding the color related? This is not about the highlight color. Why should adding an image to the background of the cell fix the layout (or scrolling of the cell's scroll view). Sorry - still don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Bringing to front `UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView` in the `layoutSubviews` of the custom cell works for me on iPhone, but not on iPad.

I have a `UITableView` in the master part of a `splitViewController` for the iPad, and in this case
the frame of the `UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView` is (768 0; 89 44), instead of (320 0; 89 44)

So I resize the frame in the `layoutSubviews` method and this works for me

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) 
    {
        for (UIView *subview2 in subview.subviews) 
        {
            if ([NSStringFromClass([subview2 class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView"]) 
            { 
                CGRect frame = subview2.frame;
                frame.origin.x = 320;
                subview2.frame = frame;
                [subview bringSubviewToFront:subview2];
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are putting content in the UITableViewCell's contentView, be sure you use `self.contentView.frame.size.width` and not `self.frame.size.width` in layoutSubviews.

`self.frame` expands width in editing mode, and will cause any content on the right to extend past the bounds of the contentView. `self.contentView.frame` stays at the correct width (and is what you should be using).

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Might be you are setting cell setBackgroundImage in cellForRowAtIndexPath (Delegate Method). Do not set this here. Set your image in:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellList.png"]]; }
```

Enjoy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to move whole contentView to the left when Delete button showing:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        var rect = contentView.frame
        rect.origin.x = self.showingDeleteConfirmation ? -15 : 38
        contentView.frame = rect
    }
}
```