# iOS7 UItableview Editing mode content overlap

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7

When I enter editing mode of `UITableView` in iOS 7, the content of my cell overlaps the delete button.
[image]

I have checked [UITableViewCell content overlaps delete button when in editing mode in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003389/uitableviewcell-content-overlaps-delete-button-when-in-editing-mode-in-ios7) question but it doesn't help in my case.

I am creating my cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method dynamically.

Please let me know if your ideas for this problem.

Comment: Take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19117382/1603072

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
 [super layoutSubviews];



self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                                    self.contentView.frame.origin.y,
                                    self.contentView.frame.size.width,
                                    self.contentView.frame.size.height);



if ((self.editing
    && (_state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask))){
    float indentPoints = self.indentationLevel * self.indentationWidth;
    self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(50,
                                        self.contentView.frame.origin.y,
                                        self.contentView.frame.size.width - indentPoints - 30,
                                        self.contentView.frame.size.height);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually use this fully implementation to get everything looking good:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
[super layoutSubviews];

self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                                    self.contentView.frame.origin.y,
                                    self.contentView.frame.size.width,
                                    self.contentView.frame.size.height);

if ((self.editing
    && ((_state & UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask)
        && !(_state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask))) ||
    ((_state & UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask)
     ))
{
    float indentPoints = self.indentationLevel * self.indentationWidth;
    self.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(50,
                                        self.contentView.frame.origin.y,
                                        self.contentView.frame.size.width - indentPoints,
                                        self.contentView.frame.size.height);
}


if ((self.editing
    && (_state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask)))
{
    float indentPoints = self.indentationLevel * self.indentationWidth;
    self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(50,
                                        self.contentView.frame.origin.y,
                                        self.contentView.frame.size.width - indentPoints - 30,
                                        self.contentView.frame.size.height);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be you are setting cell setBackgroundImage for Cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath (Delegate Method). Do not set this here. Set your image in:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellList.png"]]; }
```