# While deleting a table row entire cell moves to leftside, how to avoid that?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, ios7, uistoryboard

I have *MainStoryboard.storyboard* file for all my views creation. In that, one of my view controller scene contains *UITableView* with 3 different *UITableViewCells* in it. Out of three, two are default *UITableViewCell* whereas one is *CustomCell*. Please find the same below:

[image: For a default cell where text is displayed using cell.textLabel.text]

*(Image 1 :For a default cell where text is displayed using cell.textLabel.text)*

[image: For a custom cell where there is a custom cell class is implemented and UI is based upon storyboard design.]

*(Image 2 :For a custom cell where there is a custom cell class is implemented and UI is based upon storyboard design.)*

But, while changing this tableview to edit mode, selecting minus sign for this cell, the cell does move to left side, hence the text in it, looks like it got cropped from left side. *This happens only for **iOS7** not in **iOS6**.*

Please let me know what could be the solution for this.

Comment: Try the solution from 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003389/uitableviewcell-content-overlaps-delete-button-when-in-editing-mode-in-ios7

Answer (score 1):

Need to set AutoLayout Constraints to label in custom cell,

To right side label in custom cell add **Leading space to superview** auto layout constraint.

**Select Label in StoryBoard -> Editor -> pin -> Leading Space to SuperView.**

Comment: is there any autolayout constraints for label?

Comment: No, Its the default TableCell. So I can use cell.textLable property which is a default property of UITableViewCell