# Using background view for UITableViewCell in iOS 7 covers default delete button

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I am using background view for UITableviewCell which is an imageview, I am using the image view to achieve two side corners for first and last cell. It is working fine But the problem is when I use this background view, the default cell delete button which comes when we press the tableviewcell default edit button is being covered by the background view.If I give clear color for the background view it is working fine but I want background view to be set.

Is there any idea why the delete button is being covered or hidden by cell background view?
It happens in iOS 7
Please help! thanks in advance.

Comment: I ran across this issue in my app as well. As best I can tell it's an iOS 7 bug. The way I fixed it was by setting up some Auto Layout constraints to pin the edges of the `UIImageView` I set as the cell's `backgroundView` to the cell's `contentView`. (Don't forget to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` for the `backgroundView` to `NO` so you can use Auto Layout constraints with it.) This approach has worked fine, but I expect to see this fixed in a future version of iOS 7 (or perhaps we are both missing something).

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableViewCell delete button gets covered up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938719/uitableviewcell-delete-button-gets-covered-up)

Comment: A visual of what's going on is available in this article describing the fix I've implemented: http://sohail.io/2013/10/21/ios7-uitableviewcell-and-covered-delete-button/

Comment: This has been fixed by iOS 7.0.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spoke with an Apple UIKit engineer today at the iOS 7 Tech Talks event in SF, and confirmed that this is an open bug that will be fixed "soon" by Apple.

***UPDATE 10/22/13:*** iOS 7.0.3 fixes this issue.

Comment: I'm running iOS 7.0.3 and still experiencing this issue. Even though I have the delegate and data source methods being called correctly the Cell doesn't move when swiped and the Delete button doesn't show up, but if I tap where the Delete button should be it deletes just fine.

Comment: Still seeing this on 7.0.4

Comment: If you're still seeing this issue, you need to post a sample project/or at least sample code...otherwise there's no way we can help debug. Given that it's fixed for most everyone else, it's probably something that you're doing differently or incorrectly.

Answer (score 4):

how about instead of using the background view. just use your image as the background patternn color try using this

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:YOUR_IMAGE]];
```

Comment: I am using background imageview, because I need to preserve the top two edge corner radius, If I use it as a pattern image then the image will get repeated, Instead I want to stretch it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Had the exact same issue. Solved it by sending the backgroundView to back when transition starts & also again on the next runloop cycle (using dispatch_async).

Here's the code you should add to your cell class .m file (i.e. MyCustomTableCellView.m)

```
// Fix for iOS7, when backgroundView comes above "delete" button
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state {
    [super willTransitionToState:state];
    [self sendSubviewToBack:self.backgroundView];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self sendSubviewToBack:self.backgroundView];
    });
}

- (void)didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state {
    [super didTransitionToState:state];
    [self sendSubviewToBack:self.backgroundView];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, May I know why two times you have used sendSubviewToBack method, one in async thread?

Comment: @Techie Yeah, actually, it seems that "delete" button added after transition starts, but on the same runloop cycle (someone calls 'willTransitionToState' and after that adds the delete button immediately). So, first sendSubviewToBack doesn't help, and we want the next thing happens on main thread, after "delete" added, is to sendSubviewToBack. dispatch_async allows us to do it almost immidiately after the current function finished (after "delete" button added)

Comment: so we can use only the second one , Am I right? Please correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: That's right for today, but Apple may change implementation sometime, and since this is a hack, better stay on the safe side :)

Comment: If I use this code, will My App get rejected by apple? Can I use this code? is this legal?

Comment: This code is 100% legal, no private API calls, so no problem to submit your app with it.

Answer (score 1):

### Workaround

I found an answer in the Apple Developer Forums for a workaround. I've built on that to handle both the case for **backgroundView** and **selectedBackgroundView**.

I still see this issue in production iOS7.0.2. This workaround however, is simple and fixes the issue (for me). Drop this code into your custom UITableViewCell subclass.

You can also find it at this gist: https://gist.github.com/idStar/7018104

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [self applyEditingModeBackgroundViewPositionCorrections];
}


/**
 When using a backgroundView or selectedBackgroundView on a custom UITableViewCell 
 subclass, iOS7 currently 
 has a bug where tapping the Delete access control reveals the Delete button, only to have 
 the background cover it up again! Radar 14940393 has been filed for this. Until solved, 
 use this method in your Table Cell's layoutSubviews
 to correct the behavior.

 This solution courtesy of cyphers72 on the Apple Developer Forum, who posted the
 working solution here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/873484#873484
 */
- (void)applyEditingModeBackgroundViewPositionCorrections {
    if (!self.editing) { return; } // BAIL. This fix is not needed.

    // Assertion: we are in editing mode.

    // Do we have a regular background view?
    if (self.backgroundView) {
        // YES: So adjust the frame for that:
        CGRect backgroundViewFrame = self.backgroundView.frame;
        backgroundViewFrame.origin.x = 0;
        self.backgroundView.frame = backgroundViewFrame;
    }

    // Do we have a selected background view?
    if (self.selectedBackgroundView) {
        // YES: So adjust the frame for that:
        CGRect selectedBackgroundViewFrame = self.selectedBackgroundView.frame;
        selectedBackgroundViewFrame.origin.x = 0;
        self.selectedBackgroundView.frame = selectedBackgroundViewFrame;
    }
}
```

What we're basically doing here, is resetting the x-origin of these background views to zero at table cell layout time, if they are in editing mode. Why they are translated incorrectly, and why they are above the Apple provided 'Delete' button view is presumably, part of the known issue Apple is working to fix.

Comment: Like most, I set the backgroundView and selectedBackgroundView in code, since it's not doable (that I've found) via Storyboard prototype cells or Nibs dedicated to a single top-level item that is a table cell. In code, this (buggy) behavior is consistent whether I apply 'translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints' YES or NO to the added backgroundView (and it would make sense to keep it at YES, so that the background could stretch to whatever was needed to cover the cell).

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and finally got solution. Try this:
Instead of calling `setBackgroundImage` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (Delegate Method). Call it in `willDisplayCell`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellList.png"]];
}
```

Enjoy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Try below code may be help you.

```
[youttablecell sendSubviewToBack:yourimageview]
```