# deleting a cell from a tableview and the delete button appears behind the textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am converting my app over to IOS7 and have run into a small problem with the delete a cell function. When I activate editing and click the delete icon I get this:

[image: delete button]

(the delete button appears behind my textfield.) Any way to fix this?

Comment: its because you textfield is not getting resized. you should try autoresize on textfield.

Comment: @pawan I have Autoresize Subviews check on the cell itself and on the textfield

Comment: textfield should be in your custom cell class & in xib.

Comment: this is what you looking for cell.textField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your image view and your text field are not subviews of the cell's `contentView`.

Comment: I found my answer with the help of your answer! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938719/uitableviewcell-delete-button-gets-covered-up I used the second answer and just dropped it into my cell class.