# TableViewCell EditingStyleDelete not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Whenever I send my tableview to editing mode, I click the minus button next to a cell, and a delete button slides out on the right. (Which is normal)

However, I then have a very small amount of time in which I can successfully press this button. If I don't, it disappears pretty quickly.

I also get this error quite often:
"attempting to set a swipe to delete cell when we already have one....that doesn't seem good"

Here is my editingStyleForRowAtIndex:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
    else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }
}
```

It's like this because I only want section 2 to be editable.

(I've heard somewhere that timers can cause a problem here, and I've turned off my timer completely for trying to debug this problem, so my timer shouldn't be an issue, the property itself is even commented out.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find your answer here:

[UITableViewCell delete button gets covered up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938719/uitableviewcell-delete-button-gets-covered-up)

Seems like an iOS 7 bug but there's apparently a workaround.

Comment: Okay thanks I'll try this out!

What does it mean by "subclassing your backgroundView"?

Comment: @Inbl Instead of subclassing, do this (it seems simpler): http://stackoverflow.com/a/19222938/661749

Comment: So for this one the guy says "I did this in layoutSubviews in a UITableViewCell subclass." So I guess I just make a class that inherits from UITableViewCell and implement that method?

Comment: no you don't need to inherit from UITableViewCell, you can probably call [cell layoutSubviews] or [cell setNeedsLayout].