# Can't bring delete subview to front

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to bringtofront my subview because the delete button keeps disappearing.

```
@implementation MyCell : UITableViewCell

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {

        for (UIView *subview2 in subview.subviews) {

            NSLog(@"HERE!");
            if ([NSStringFromClass([subview2 class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView"]) {
                NSLog(@"got inside the if!");
                [subview2 sendSubviewToBack:subview];
                [subview bringSubviewToFront:subview2];
                [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:subview2];

            }
        }
    }
}

@end
```

I subclassed UITableViewCell. Both the NSLogs are printing so I know it's getting in there, but I've tried all 3 of these methods to put the view in front. Any ideas why this wouldn't be working?

Comment: You need to put all of your custom cell's custom views in the cell's `self.contentView`, not directly in `self`.

Comment: Like this `[self.contentview sendSubviewToBack:subview];`
                `[self.contentview bringSubviewToFront:subview2];`
                `[self.contentview bringSubviewToFront:subview2];` instead?

Comment: No. When you add the subviews, add them to the `contentView`. Then none of this code will be needed.

Comment: Get rid of this `layoutSubviews` method. You don't need it. Update your question with the code where you add the subviews to this custom cell.

Comment: I'm never adding subviews, I just set the style to editing.

Comment: If you never add any subviews, why the custom cell class?

Comment: So I can implement the layoutSubviews method

Comment: None of this should necessary. What version of iOS are you seeing this problem with? Show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Maybe you have something wrong there.

Comment: It's iOS 7. I tried this based on a suggestion since there's apparently a known bug with the delete style for Cells.

Comment: Which version of iOS 7? Are you setting the cell's `selectedBackgroundView`? If so, Apple fixed this in 7.0.3.

Comment: I'm using 7.0.3. I'm not setting selectedBackgroundView anywhere. The answer in this thread is what I was following. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938719/uitableviewcell-delete-button-gets-covered-up

Comment: Try 7.0.6. You really should be anyway due to the major security fix in that update.

Comment: Actually it was just my simulator on 7.0.3. The one on my phone was updated earlier today but the problem is sticking around.

Answer (score 0):

`subview2` is a subview of `subview`, which is a subview of `self`. The receiver of the `sendSubviewToBack:` or `bringSubviewToFront:` message must be the superview of the view given as argument. Therefore only the second one of the calls you make is valid. The correct calls would be

```
[self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
[self bringSubviewToFront:subview];
[subview bringSubviewToFront:subview2];
```

(And the same for `sendSubviewToBack:`.)

As for your actual problem, I can't figure out the view hierarchy you are using from the code posted, but it seems that it is incorrect. You should probably not have your custom views as direct subviews of `self`, but rather as subviews of `self.contentView` (as per [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/contentView)).

Comment: I tried it both ways and the delete button is still disappearing right after I click the minus button.

Comment: My view hierarchy is pretty simple, just a UITableView populated with MyCells which inherit from UITableViewCell.

Comment: How would I go about changing the parent view of a cell? Inside cellForRowAtIndexPath? Or would somewhere else be better?

Comment: @Inbl You don't change the parent view of the cell, you change how you add the subviews of your custom cell.

Comment: I don't think I'm ever adding subviews to my custom cell, I just set editing style to YES.

Comment: @Inbl So, wait, you're only using the default editing functionality and it doesn't work? Perhaps the problem is that your handler for the press of the button turns off the editing mode…

Comment: All I do is `return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;` so I don't know why that would happen.